# Difference between 会いに vs 会って

Tags: usage

What's the difference between these two ways of saying "I'm driving to meet a friend"?

> 俺は友達に**会いに**運転している
>
> 俺は友達に**会って**運転している

Is this the difference between between V-stem and V-te conjunctives, one is written and the other colloquial?

Comment: @user3856370 I didn't see it anywhere, actually. See, you can use V-stem with に行く to mean "go to do". My thinking was that I could use the same construction with something other than 行く to express an action with a purpose behind it. I tried a few variations on it, and online translators understood it, which made me think I was doing something right.

Comment: @LonelyDriver Do you mean 会いに行く

Comment: @Ringil, I totally did. Oopsie. Thanks for noticing it. Anyway, the question still stands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the form 「連用形(continuative form)+に+移動動詞(motion verb)」, the 移動動詞 can be 行く, 来る, 帰る, 戻る, 出る, 出かける, 入る, etc.

> ◎「会いに行く」"go to see" 「会いに来る」"come to see" 「会いに帰る」"come back to see" ...
> ✕「会いに運転する」 sounds incorrect.

Related threads:

- [Is it true that only movement verbs can take [V-stem]に to express a purpose?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2957/9831)
- [When can you use (masu stem) + (another verb)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/82921/9831)
- [Usage of に after verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54211/9831)

---

俺は友達に会って運転している would be interpreted as "I met my friend and am driving."

To say "I'm driving to meet my friend", I would probably say...

> 「車で友達に会いに行く(ところだ)」 *lit.* I'm (on my way) going to meet a friend by car.

Comment: Live and learn. Thank you.
But as for 俺は友達に会って運転している, wouldn't it be interpreted differently based on context? You can use -te for purpose as in 俺は友達に会って運転している "I stopped a bullet to save her", at least if this lesson is to be believed https://jn1et.com/howto-tekei/#toc22. But again, if it's unnatural to say things like that, I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: `"I stopped a bullet to save her"` -- You mean 私は彼女をかばって銃弾を受けた? In that sentence, 彼女をかばう and 銃弾を受ける happen at the same time. The ～て is more like "in the manner of~~" or "while doing so" than genuine "for the purpose of". 友達に会う and 運転する *might* happen at the same time, but "I am meeting a friend and am driving", "I am driving while meeting a friend" won't be natural.

Comment: Awesome. That helps a lot. Thanks again.